# Animate one progress bar at a time

Tags: javascript, css, progress-bar, viewport, onscroll

I have some progress bars on my project that animate on scroll. The problem is that all of them animate as soon as the first one comes in the viewport. So what I want is to make one progress bar animate at a time as they come into the viewport.

[**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xVxaeO)

**JS**

```
function isScrolledIntoView(elem)
{
    var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

    var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

    return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
}

var IsViewed = false;

$(document).scroll(function () {

  if(isScrolledIntoView('#progress-bar') && !IsViewed){
$('.bar-percentage[data-percentage]').each(function () {
  var progress = $(this);
  var percentage = Math.ceil($(this).attr('data-percentage'));
  $({countNum: 0}).animate({countNum: percentage}, {
    duration: 3500,
    easing:'swing',
    step: function() {
      // What todo on every count
    var pct = '';
    if(percentage == 0){
      pct = Math.floor(this.countNum) + '%';
    }else{
      pct = Math.floor(this.countNum+1) + '%';
    }
    progress.text(pct) && progress.siblings().children().css('width',pct);
    }
  });
});
    IsViewed = true;
  }
});
```

Thank you!

Comment: you have multiple elements on the same page with the same id. this is invalid. it may be contributing to your issue. if you need to reference multiple elements in one go, either use a common class name or a common data attribute.

Comment: ...and how do I do that? Sorry for asking as my JS skills are very limited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Use `:eq` with global variable `index` and in `complete` callback of `animate`, increase the `index` and call the same function again.

*[`:eq() Selector`](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) Select the element at index n within the matched set*

Try this:

```js
function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {
  var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

  var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
  var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

  return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
}

var IsViewed = false;
var index = 0;

function animateThis() {
  var progress = $('.bar-percentage[data-percentage]:eq("' + index + '")');
  var percentage = Math.ceil(progress.attr('data-percentage'));
  progress.animate({
    countNum: percentage
  }, {
    duration: 3500,
    easing: 'swing',
    step: function() {
      // What todo on every count
      var pct = '';
      if (percentage == 0) {
        pct = Math.floor(this.countNum) + '%';
      } else {
        pct = Math.floor(this.countNum + 1) + '%';
      }
      progress.text(pct) && progress.siblings().children().css('width', pct);
    },
    complete: function() {
      ++index;
      animateThis();
    }
  });
}

$(document).scroll(function() {

  if (isScrolledIntoView('#progress-bar') && !IsViewed) {

    animateThis()
    IsViewed = true;
  }
});
```

```css
.textbox {
  height: 700px;
}
#progress-bar {
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px auto;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  color: #000;
}
.bar-label {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #000;
  text-transform: none;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.bar-percentage {
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  right: 0;
}
.bar-container {
  height: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #EFEFEF;
}
.bar {
  float: left;
  background: #000;
  height: 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="textbox">
  <p>Scroll down to see progress bars</p>
</div>
<div id="progress-bar" class="thick-bar">
  <div class="bar-label">Web Design</div>
  <div class="bar-percentage" data-percentage="95"></div>
  <div class="bar-container">
    <div class="bar"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="progress-bar" class="thick-bar">
  <div class="bar-label">Graphic Design</div>
  <div class="bar-percentage" data-percentage="72"></div>
  <div class="bar-container">
    <div class="bar"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="progress-bar" class="thick-bar">
  <div class="bar-label">Web Development</div>
  <div class="bar-percentage" data-percentage="87"></div>
  <div class="bar-container">
    <div class="bar"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="progress-bar" class="thick-bar">
  <div class="bar-label">Branding</div>
  <div class="bar-percentage" data-percentage="65"></div>
  <div class="bar-container">
    <div class="bar"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[**Fiddle here**](https://jsfiddle.net/20vy62yj/)

Comment: Glad it helped! _Happy Coding_

Comment: Seems they just execute one after another, not when they enter the viewport.